# Segues from cells in UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

Could someone help with segues from dynamic prototype's cells?

I have one "menu" `TableViewController` with prototype cells.
There is array of cells:

```
let converterItems = ["Time", "Pressure", "Lenght", "Power"]
let converterImages = ["imageTime", "imagePressure", "imageLenght", "imagePower"]
```

And TableView funcs:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return converterItems.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mainCell", for: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell

        cell.labelMain.text = converterItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.imageMain.image = converterImages[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 60;
    }
```

I assume that I must use `didselectatrow`, but there a lot of errors.
Every cell must goes to it's `View`.

Comment: did you create a segue for each item? are there 4 segues in your storyboard? ideally with the names as they appear in `converterItems`

Comment: what kind of errors?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ  it helps, thanks!

Comment: upvote would be enough

Comment: @MilanNosáľ couldnt upvoting)

Comment: then you could just let it be

Comment: really it's ridiculous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // assuming that for each converterItem there is a segue
    // e.g.: for Time there is timeSegue
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "\(converterItems[indexPath.row].lowercased())Segue", sender: indexPath)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `didSelectRowAt` we write `performSegue` method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "timeSegue", sender: "Time")
    }
```

Where "timeSegue" - is Segue name and "Time" - is cell name.

Comment: not working. When written a lot of segues its begin shows all of it

Answer (score 0):

```
let segues= ["timeSegue", "pressureSegue", "LenghtSegue", "powerSegue"]
```

/////

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

   performSegue(withIdentifier: "\(segues[indexPath.row])", sender: indexPath)

 }
```